# How to fix networks conflict between WSL and Docker compose?

Tags: networking, server, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker

Few days ago, on **WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04)**, I installed docker compose and created a docker-compose.yml that builds a database based on postgres:12 image. The first time I ran it, everything worked fine.

A few days later, when I ran my docker compose again, the build didn't work. **Docker cannot access to internet to pull the postgres image, the connection is refused**. Here is what it said :

```
$ docker compose up -d

[+] Running 1/0
 ! database Warning                                                                                                                              
[+] Building 0.0s (3/3) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                
 => => transferring dockerfile: 290B                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                   
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                     
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/postgres:12-alpine                                                                         
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/postgres:12-alpine:
------
failed to solve: postgres:12-alpine: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/postgres/manifests/12-alpine": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 172.18.0.1:53: read udp 172.18.0.1:51217->172.18.0.1:53: read: connection refused
```

So I checked if I still had an Internet access in WSL by trying `sudo apt-get update` or `ping google.com` and I didn't...The fact is I just don't have any internet access anymore in WSL since that day.

```
$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

### What I have tried :

- I tried to go into `/etc/resolve.conf` and modify nameserver address by enter google DNS, `8.8.8.8`, instead of the default address. resolve.conf content :

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateR.esolvConf = false
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I have even created a `wsl.conf` to keep the `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. After that, my problem was fixed for a few minutes but it all crashes again.

- The docker error is not the same if I change nameserver in `resolve.conf`. With default nameserver, if I want to pull postgres image in docker, I have a **connection refused** (like with docker compose) :

```
$ docker pull postgres
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 172.18.0.1:53: read udp 172.18.0.1:57439->172.18.0.1:53: read: connection refused
```

And with `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, I have a **timeout** error from docker :

```
$ docker pull postgres
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 8.8.8.8:53: read udp 172.18.7.177:46999->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
```

- Strange thing though, **if I reboot my PC and then run WSL, I have an ephemere internet connection, around 2mins**, (if i do a `sudo apt-get update`, it works), and it finally loses any connection then.

I think docker or docker compose must have created conflict in my WSL networks, maybe an IP address already used by something else, but I can't explain how. Here is my Docker and Docker compose version.

```
Docker version 23.0.3, build 3e7cbfd
Docker Compose version v2.17.2
```

Thanks for your help, I honestly don't know what to do.

Comment: What do you get from `ip route`?